# How to replace the phone number in my Yahoo account?

Tags: yahoo-mail, yahoo, yahoo-account

How to replace the mobile phone number in my Yahoo email?

Answer (score 1):

From Yahoo! help:

> 1. [Sign in to your Account Info page](https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.done=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.yahoo.com%2Faccount%2Fpersonalinfo).
> 2. Information you can change includes:
>
>    - **Personal info** - Edit your name, address, **phone number**, alternate email addresses, or primary email address.

See this -> [To change your listed mobile number in Yahoo Messenger](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN1457.html).